# Solve for $x$ in the given inequality:

Tags: trigonometry, inequality

Solve:
$$(\cot^{-1} (x))^2 - 4\cot^{-1} (x) + 3 \geq 0$$.

My Attempt:
 $$(\cot^{-1} (x))^2 - 4\cot^{-1} (x) + 3 \geq 0$$.
Let $\cot^{-1} (x)=t$. then

$$t^2-4t+3\geq 0$$
$$(t-3)(t-1)\geq 0$$
Either, $\cot^{-1} (x) \leq 1$

Or, $\cot^{-1} (x) \geq 3$

I solved till here, but couldn't get the answer given in book. The answer in book is $x \in (-\infty, \cot (3)] \cup [\cot (3), \infty )$.

Comment: The answer clearly has a typo in it. You're right.

Answer (score 0):

The hint: $\cot^{-1}$ is a decreasing function for $x>0$ and for $x<0$.

Answer (score 0):

arccot x > 3, so now "cot" both sides of this inequality.  This will give you x > cot 3.  Do this with arccot x < 1 as well.  This will give you two disjoint sets of numbers whose union is the solution.

Comment: $\cot$ is a decreasing function.